# JSQMessagesViewController build error when I try to run on device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i'm using Xcode 7.3.1, my project run and compile on simulator, but when I try to run on my device (iPhone 6S) i getting this error

I installed by cocoa pods (1.0.0)

please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clean your derived data. And then rebuild. Select the Window option in the top bar find Projects option and delete the project folder. Then build and run. I think the command for deleting derived data is `Command Shift k` then pod install again.

Comment: Also update your pod it no longer has JSQSoundPlayer apart of it